# Includes() only in the first word of a String

Tags: javascript, string, methods

Hi I would like to run `includes()` method only on the first word of a String. I have found that there is an optional parameter `fromIndex`. I would rather need to specify `toIndex` which value would be the index of first whitespace but something like that does not seem to exist.

Do you have any idea how I could achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Please add some test case and your effort

Answer (score 1):

You've said you have a `toIndex` in mind, so two options:

1. Use `indexOf` instead:

   ```
   var n = str.indexOf(substr);
   if (n != -1 && n < toIndex) {
       // It's before `toIndex`
   }
   ```
2. Split off the first word (using `split` or `substring` or whatever) and then use `includes` on it:

   ```
   if (str.substring(0, toIndex).includes(substr)) {
       // It's before `toIndex`
   }
   ```

(Adjust the use of `toIndex` above based on whether you want it inclusive or exclusive, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a sentence, just split the string to get the first word

```js
myString = "This is my string";
firstWord = myString.split(" ")[0];
console.log("this doesn't include what I'm looking for".includes(firstWord));
console.log("This does".includes(firstWord));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach and create a new method

```js
let str = "abc abdf abcd";
String.prototype.includes2 = function(pattern,from =0,to = 0) {
  to = this.indexOf(' ');
  to = to >0?to: this.length();
  return this.substring(from, to).includes(pattern);
}
console.log(str.includes2("abc",0,3));
console.log(str.includes2("abc",4,8));
console.log(str.includes2("abc"));
console.log(str.includes2("abd"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string and pass to the include method with index 0

```js
var a = "this is first word of a String";
console.log(a.includes(a.split(' ')[0]));
```